# Spring MVC @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring

Имеется два пути определенных в разных контроллерах:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/employee/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public RUser getObject(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long objectId, Model model){/*код*/}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/rest/job/list"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public PageResult getSimpleList(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session){/*код*/}
```

Вопрос следующий, вот из первого пути, мне нужно брать значение PathVariable, подставлять в код во втором, для выполнения некоторых операций.
Суть в том, что первый путь отражает переход на форму редактирования, а второй- списковую форму на вкладке на этой форме редактирования.
Как же мне забирать значение PathVariable, если это вообще возможно

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что хотите сделать. Когда выполняется второй метод при открытии формы?

Comment: Методы контроллера не стоит связывать между собой, это плохая практика. Лучше передавайте этот `id` например как get-параметр `/rest/job/list`

Comment: Когда выполняется второй метод, должны отображаться работы связанные только с данным сотрудником.@iksuy а можно подробнее про передачу как get-параметра?

Comment: Можно указать компоненту срок жизненного цикла как "сессия" и хранить результаты работы методов как поля класса. Ещё можно хранить значения нужных параметров непосредственно в HttpSession (set/getAttribute).